# Search and replace strings in PDF with Perl, Ruby, or PHP

Tags: string, search, pdf, replace

Is there a way to script replacing strings in PDF documents? I can use either Perl, Ruby or PHP. If possible, a regular expression would be a great.

Comment: Are you using this for a template on a webserver?

Answer (score 2):

As part of my open-source [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/) Perl library, I include a tiny front-end program called [changepagestring.pl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/bin/changepagestring.pl) which does what you ask.

However, it only replaces text that's contiguous in the PDF syntax.  If you switch fonts, size, style, etc. mid-phrase then it won't match.  If you do any advanced kerning then it won't match.

Those limitations aside, it's really easy to use and it's simple enough that you can easily fork it and hack it to your needs.

Comment: nice work! I hope these limitation will be removed in its next version. :)

Comment: @santosh not likely. Those limitations have existed since CAM::PDF 0.01 and are unlikely to ever change.  It's too hard a problem to solve in my spare time and nobody has been willing to fund the work to date.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, you can parse the contents of your PDF using the [PDF::API2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDF-API2/lib/PDF/API2.pm) module. You should then be able to search and replace your target strings in the usual way (`s///`), and write the new document back to disk.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I've searched through CPAN documentation of PDF::API2 module but found nothing concerning substitution.

Thanks.